# WPF textbox style throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

The following style causes the exception "'ContentElement' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid'" when the textbox it's applied to goes into the disabled state.  I've added comments at the spot of the foul.  Any idea how I can correct this and not just comment it out?

```
<Style x:Key="ThemedTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="ReadOnly"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1" To="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <!--************** This is where the problem is **************-->
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="#FF808080"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames-->
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard/>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverState" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                    <Storyboard/>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="NormalState">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxBackgroundGradient}">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxStroke}">
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Height="Auto" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxHighlightGradient}"/>

                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="MouseOverState" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxBackgroundGradient}"/>
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxStroke}"/>
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Height="Auto" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxMouseOverHighlight}"/>

                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="DisabledState" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Fill="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxDisabledBackground}"/>
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="0" Stroke="{StaticResource GlossyBlack_TextBoxStroke}"/>

                        </Grid>

                        <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="4,4,4,4" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: How can it work if you have no element with name ContentElement known to your style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to specify target at all, remove it and things should start to work

```
Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"
```

it looks like a simple copy/paste mistake. But just in case, you shouldn't have to specify target on your own style trigger (only if it's in the template trigger and you are manipulating various elements in the template, or the animation is declared outside of your style, and you have to reference an element...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the intention of providing a ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames was to do some color animation when the box changes from being enabled to being disabled.

However, your DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames, which controls the opacity of the background grids already pretty much does that job so I don't think you need to include the ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

As others have said, your immediate problem is exactly what the error message says: the ControlTemplate does not have an element called "ContentElement" in it. Your best bet will be just to remove the whole of the ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames I think.

Answer (score -1):

Is the name of your TextBox "ContentElement", if not, it should be.

If you look at the example in the documentation...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx

...then you will see that the Storyboard.TargetName must be given the name of a valid item in your XAML.

Comment: The "ContentElement" mentioned does not refer to the name of the whole TextBox, it should refer to an element defined within the ControlTemplate in which it is mentioned. Calling the TextBox "ContentElement" will not help, as the template cannot see outside itself.

Comment: Uh Bob...you should pay attention before dropping a negative. The questioner said he was applying it to the TextBox. If he put the name of the TextBox there, it would work.

Denis Moroov is also correct as you can remove that line altogether.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, your proposal was to declare the TextBox with the style that the questioner has defined. i.e. <TextBox x:Name="ContentElement" Style="{StaticResource ThemedTextBox}"/>. Unfortunately this does not work, as the ContentTemplate defined within the Style resource cannot see that TextBox. If I've misunderstood you, please clarify what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: I meant like the example in the documentation.

Comment: The example in the documentation is not a Storyboard defined within a ControlTemplate, as in the questioner's example. I'm not trying to be difficult, but I just think you've slightly misunderstood the purpose (if there is one) of the Storyboard target mentioned in the question. It is meant to refer to some control within the template of the TextBox, not to the whole TextBox itself.

Comment: No worries. Its always hard to be clear in a short question or answer. We just try to help out and this time Denis hit the answer right on the nose.